# Is there number of request limit for sending HTTP request from Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I'm working with firebase cloud function.
My function is triggered every 5-minutes.
When my function is triggered, my function send HTTP request to external websites.
If number of websites is less than 10, everything is ok.
But, when number of websites is greater than 10, timeout error occurs.
Can you explain why? any solution? see below code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp();
const rp = require('request-promise');

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('*/5 * * * *')
    .timeZone("Asia/Tokyo").onRun((context) => {

    // URLs  
    const urlArray = ['http://a.com', /* ..... */, 'http://z.com']; // total 25 urls.

    function getDataFromUrl(){
        const promises = []
        var   N = 10     // if N<=10 working well, but if N>10 not working
        for(var i=0; i<N; i++){              
            promises.push(rp.get(urlArray[i]))
        }
        return Promise.all(promises)
    }

    return getDataFromUrl().then(results =>{
        results.forEach(result=>{
            // do something
        })
    })

}
```

Comment: Maybe try running your script in a Compute Engine instance manually and see if it manifests a similar puzzle.  Also, where is the timeout error being thrown from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we can't benchmark your code for you, or observe how it's behaving, the only logical answer is that at least one of the ten is taking longer than your configured timeout, which makes the entire set of promises fail when sent through `Promise.all()`.  Try [increasing the timeout](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) for that function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer(I saw your YouTube video, and I've learn a lot from your video. thanks..^^) My configured timeout is 60secs. When N=10, my function is completed within 10 secs. When I try "for(var i=1; i=11; i++){....}", every thing is OK. So, I think 11's website is not cause of this problem. Only when number of rp.get() exceeds 10, timeout error occurs.

Comment: There's not enough information here to provide a specific answer.  You're going to have to benchmark and debug this on your own.  The number of requests shouldn't make much of a difference.  It's the behavior of the individual requests that matter, and we don't know what those are.